# Set Windows Host Name

Tags: java, windows, ip, hostname

I am using

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
```

to get the windows host name (I know there are many different hostname and many different calls but this is the one I want).

How do I set the hostname using Java that the above function will give me what I set?